# How to get UTM paramters in activity when Clicked on Dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking

I am using Firebase Dynamic link when I click on it I get the deep link in activity, but how to get UTM parameters inside activity like how I get the deep link

Answer (score 0):

try the following code for getting UTM parameters

```
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        }
                        if (deepLink != null
                                && deepLink.getBooleanQueryParameter("utm_param1", false)) {
                            String utm_param1 = deepLink.getQueryParameter("utm_param1");
                        }
                    }
                });
```